# When retrieving information from database and loading it into textboxes, data disappears after a single quote

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure if I am missing anything from my code to retrieve text from mysql. The data pulls out fine if it's not in a textbox. If I load it into a textbox, then everything after a single quote disappears. So let's say I have the word "let's make this happen" as an entry, all that the textbox would display is "let". I've attached the code below for my while loop which works.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='id[$i]' value=" . $row['id'] . ">";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='resident[$i]' style='width: 80px' type='text' value='" . $row['r_name'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='room_n[$i]' style='width: 40px' type='text' value='" . $row['room'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='appt_time[$i]' style='width: 55px' type='text' value='" . date("g:i A", strtotime($row['appttime'])) . "' /></td>";  
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='appt_phone[$i]' style='width: 65px' type='text' value='" . $row['apptphone'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='name_l[$i]' style='width: 80px' type='text' value='" . $row['l_name'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='address[$i]' style='width: 90px' type='text' value='" . $row['address'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='city[$i]' style='width: 70px' type='text' value='" . $row['city'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='zip[$i]' style='width: 50px' type='text' value='" . $row['zip'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='buscar[$i]' style='width: 30px' type='text' value='" . $row['buscar'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='e_name[$i]' style='width: 60px' type='text' value='" . $row['escort_name'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='transfer[$i]' style='width: 40px' type='text' value='" . $row['transfer'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='comments[$i]' style='width: 80px' type='text' value='" . $row['comments'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='out[$i]' style='width: 70px' type='text' value='" . date("g:i A", strtotime($row['depart'])) . "' /></td>";
  echo "<td align='center'><input name='delete[$i]' type='checkbox' value='" . $row['id'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  ++$i;  
  }

echo "</table>";
```

Thank you for your help :). I'm sure I'm just missing something small.

Comment: *"I've attached the code below for my while loop which works."* - Ok, so show us the code that **doesn't** work.

Comment: View the source of the page once it's rendered and you'll see why -- you need to unescape things if you escape before inserting into the database.

Comment: That is the code that pulls out the info from my database. The part of the code that doesn't seem to work is pulling anything out of the db with a single quote.

Comment: for the sake of god you can do this with only one echo

Comment: lol, i could, but it displays nicer on my screen this way. so yeah, it inserts just fine into the db, but when i go to retrieve it, anything after the single quote disappears, but only if i load it into the texbox, if I load it on the page, it's just fine.

Comment: (as an aside, the `<input>` tag isn't supported as a child of the `<table>` tag and should be moved into a `<tr><td><inputgoeshere></td></tr>` situation. Also, if possible, use CSS classes to style those elements rather than throwing in that hard-coded, in-line style php code)  Without knowing some of your content, it's difficult to say. My guess is that you have an unescaped `>` or `/` in your data that breaks the page when output.

Comment: Try to strip double quote " in the data that comes to your database.. :)

Comment: Just ignore the code for one moment, how would you pull data from a database into textboxes? Also, how do you make sure that don't doesn't turn into don?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the source of the data. You've got to create valid HTML output, so escape it for HTML, i.e. with `. htmlspecialchars($row['r_name'], ENT_QUOTES) .`, see the manual to [htmlspecialchars](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to get an O'Brien correctly in the value attribute.

Comment: Thank you VMai, that totally worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to scape special characters.

Use:
    addslashes($row["your_value"])